# Play Asset Delivery in React Native Android

Tags: android, react-native, android-asset-delivery, android-assetpacks

I have an app it has a lot of audio and image assets, i'm not being able to upload app to Google Play, I want to try to use Play Asset Delivery

I followed this blog ([faltutech blog article](https://blog.faltutech.com/2023/android/02/13/play-asset-delivery-react-native/)) but I can't find how to use it in React Native, I just want to separate the audio and images individually and use in React native.

[android folder structure is like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pnlx.png)

also created
assets.ios.ts

```
export const data = {
    image: require('../../../android/g_asset_pack/src/main/assets/images')
}
```

asset.android.ts

```
export const data = {
    image: '../../../android/g_asset_pack/src/main/assets'
}
```

i'm trying to loading image like

```
<Image source={{ uri: "assets:images/Final_Art.jpeg" }} style={{height:100,width:200,resizeMode:'cover'}}/>
```

but its not loading it.